# Unable to generate multi page PDF in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I have an html file which contains static and dynamic data both, and I need to generate a PDF file from that html file. I am able to create PDF file but it only prints the first page. I need a three page PDF File. I have used following two functions to draw and save the PDF file.
My code is :

```
func exportHTMLContentToPDF(HTMLContent: String) {

    let printFormatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: HTMLContent)

    let printPageRenderer = CustomPrintPageRenderer()

    printPageRenderer.addPrintFormatter(printFormatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)

    let pdfData = drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer(printPageRenderer: printPageRenderer)

    pdfFilename = "\(AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().getDocDir())/FinalPdf.pdf"

    pdfData?.write(toFile: pdfFilename, atomically: true)

    print(pdfFilename)

}

func drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer(printPageRenderer: UIPrintPageRenderer) -> NSData! {

    let data = NSMutableData()

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRect.zero, nil)

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()

    printPageRenderer.drawPage(at: 0, in: UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds())

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

    return data

}
```

I have followed app coda tutorial for this. For multiple pages, it says to include the beginning of the PDF page creation and the print page renderer drawing into a loop. Please help me to create multiple page PDF.

Comment: Read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH10-SW1

Answer (score 6):

Use the code below in place of your current drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer function:

```
func drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer(printPageRenderer: UIPrintPageRenderer) -> NSData! {
    let data = NSMutableData()

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRect.zero, nil)
    printPageRenderer.prepare(forDrawingPages: NSMakeRange(0, printPageRenderer.numberOfPages))

    let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()

    for i in 0...(printPageRenderer.numberOfPages - 1) {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
        printPageRenderer.drawPage(at: i, in: bounds)
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    return data
}
```

Viola, multiple page's.